# How can I create a rule in Outlook that will automatically save & unzip an attachment when an email arrives?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, attachments

I get a regular email about our site's web stats from WebTrends, but it comes as a zipped attachment.  I'm wondering if there's a simple way to have a rule run a script that will unzip the attachment and save it to a local folder?

I'm running Outlook 2003 SP3 on Win7 if that matters

**Update:** Thanks for the plugin options, but I was really hoping for a non-third party solution.  Office supports macros & scripts & windows can unzip natively, there must be a way of firing a script that will do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**EZDetach Outlook add-on**](http://www.techhit.com/ezdetach/outlook_attachments.html) can do this, but it's not free unfortunately:

> **EZDetach Features**
>
> - ...
> - Zip / Unzip attachments on the fly.
> - ...
> - Automatically save attachments with Outlook rules (custom rule
>     action).
> - ...
> - Compatible with Outlook 2000, 2002 (XP), 2003 and 2007.
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

[Attachments Processor for Outlook](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/attachments_processor/) can do this and much much more.

> Attachment Processor is a powerful
>   multifunctional manager of attached
>   files in the Microsoft Outlook
>   messages.
>
> **The program can:**
>
> - automatically extract attachments from the incoming messages and save
>     them to your hard disk (extracted
>     attachments are replaced in the
>     incoming message with a link to the
>     file on the disk or a text file with
>     an attachment description as well and
>     a link to it)
> - automatically pack the attachments by ZIP in the outgoing messages
> - create password-protected archives
> - automatically pack by ZIP all incoming attachments or only specific
>     attachment types
> - **automatically unzip all incoming attachments. Attachments Processor
>     works in Simple and Advanced modes. In
>     the Advanced mode the user can set up
>     individual rules for processing
>     attachments in different messages and
>     folders.**

Attachments Processor is shareware. Try it free for 30 days before considering a purchase.